# What does "*" signify in the below lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

```
intersection = lambda *p: list(set(p[1]) & set(p[2]))
```

I kinda get lambda functions but am completely thrown by the *p here. Can anyone explain?

Comment: if you remove `*`, script still work or not? can you paste working example?

Comment: that just signifies variadic positional arguments, like `def intersection(*p): ...` note, generally, you shouldn't assign the result of a lambda expression to a name, at least according to PEP8, because it defeats the only purpose of a lambda, which is to be anonymous, so you might as well use a regular function definition statement instead of the lambda expression